# Looking to explode wood block in 2.8

Tags: modeling

I am looking to explode a wood block and reveal a text logo in blender 2.8. My original idea was to make cube with a remesh modifer and apply with a quick explode. The problem was that no matter what I did there was a bug in the code that wouldn't apply the explosion correctly.

My second attempt was to make a cube ND Subdivide it with loop cuts it accepted the quick explode but the result was not a real explosion, the particles just pealed off of the cube but would not lay down in a pile or without a collision set up they would not all fall through the floor correctly. Either way I was looking to explode the  cube not to have it just fall to pieces.

Idea?[image]s

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at Cell Fracturing, either the standard in-build one or the standalone add-on version. There are many great tutorials for it on YouTube, too.

Maybe you can adapt this tutorial from CGGeek? You only need to add a ground (rigid body, passive type), play with the shard settings (wood usually has a high number of long splinters) and maybe use an object to push the wood from behind instead of below. Also, no smoke sim needed, obviously.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J70DijACZm0

Another (older) tutorial, could serve as a reference for settings:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_m81zF9WtY